# What happens when sending multiple messages on WSADuplicateSocket?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

I'm looking for some information on what happens when sending at the same time on a WSA socket that had been duplicated?  Is that safe?  Can you point me to any specific docs?

Do I need to have some sort of message across the processes to tell which process to be active for sends?  I assume I have to do that for receives.

Can anyone give me an example of what this portion of the documentation means?

> Notification on shared sockets is subject to the usual constraints of WSAAsyncSelect and WSAEventSelect. Issuing either of these calls using any of the shared descriptors cancels any previous event registration for the socket, regardless of which descriptor was used to make that registration. Thus, a shared socket cannot deliver FD_READ events to process A and FD_WRITE events to process B. For situations when such tight coordination is required, developers would be advised to use threads instead of separate processes.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565.aspx) states:

> The descriptors that reference a shared socket can be used independently for I/O. However, **the Windows Sockets interface does not implement any type of access control, so it is up to the processes involved to coordinate their operations on a shared socket.** Shared sockets are typically used to having one process that is responsible for creating sockets and establishing connections, and other processes that are responsible for information exchange.

If you have two processes sending on a shared socket at the same time, they are going to overlap each other.  The same as if two threads within a single process send to the same socket at the same time.  So you need to coordinate the sends to avoid the overlap.  You can use a shared named mutex for that, for instance.

As for the quote you asked about, it should be self-explanatory if you read the relevant documentation:

[`WSAAsyncSelect()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540.aspx)

> Issuing a WSAAsyncSelect for a socket cancels any previous WSAAsyncSelect or WSAEventSelect for the same socket. For example, to receive notification for both reading and writing, the application must call WSAAsyncSelect with both FD_READ and FD_WRITE, as follows:
>
> rc = WSAAsyncSelect(s, hWnd, wMsg, FD_READ|FD_WRITE);
>
> It is not possible to specify different messages for different events. The following code will not work; the second call will cancel the effects of the first, and only FD_WRITE events will be reported with message wMsg2:
>
> rc = WSAAsyncSelect(s, hWnd, wMsg1, FD_READ);
>   rc = WSAAsyncSelect(s, hWnd, wMsg2, FD_WRITE);

[`WSAEventSelect()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576.aspx)

> Issuing a WSAEventSelect for a socket cancels any previous WSAAsyncSelect or WSAEventSelect for the same socket and clears the internal network event record. For example, to associate an event object with both reading and writing network events, the application must call WSAEventSelect with both FD_READ and FD_WRITE, as follows:
>
> rc = WSAEventSelect(s, hEventObject, FD_READ|FD_WRITE);
>
> It is not possible to specify different event objects for different network events. The following code will not work; the second call will cancel the effects of the first, and only the FD_WRITE network event will be associated with hEventObject2:
>
> rc = WSAEventSelect(s, hEventObject1, FD_READ);
>   rc = WSAEventSelect(s, hEventObject2, FD_WRITE); //bad

So, if you have process `S` sharing a socket with processes `A` and `B`, you can't have `A` listening for `FD_READ` events and `B` listening for `FD_WRITE` events, or vice versa.  It is an all-or-nothing deal.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is as safe as writing to the same socket from two threads. The actual send() function is atomic: no-one else can enter it for the same socket while you're in it. So you won't get data interleaving, *provided* you are writing entire messages with a single send(), *and* you're in blocking mode: see comments below.
2. Only if you're violating the condition above.
3. It implies that really only one of the processes can use select() on that socket concurrently. As soon as one process does that, the other process loses its 'interest' in whatever it was selecting on, so none of those events will fire. This is usually exactly what you want, as you don't want both processes reacting to the same read event. However it's more problematic if you're also selecting on write. If you're not selecting at all, don't worry about this.

Comment: Even if `send()` were atomic, there is no guarantee that passing a whole message to a single `send()` call will actually send the whole message, if there is not enough buffer space for it, an especially if the socket is non-blocking. Never assume that writing to the same socket from multiple threads will not overlap/interleave data, because it can, thus corrupting the messages being sent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *Only* if the socket is non-blocking. If the socket is blocking, send(), err, blocks. It's required by Posix among other things. Such a guarantee is also specifically mentioned in the MSDN documentation. Interleaving can therefore only happen in non-blocking mode.

Comment: `send()` on a blocking socket can be interrupted by `SO_SNDTIMEO` and APCs.  So again, you can not truly guarantee that a blocking `send()` will *always* send an entire message at one time. You have to check the return value to make sure. It is safer to be explicit and use your own locking mechanism to hold exclusive write access to the socket until the entire message has finished being sent.